# Math to Math Nerdy Love Expressions....Fillin the Blanks

Tags: knowledge, no-computers, humor

1) My Love for you is like  $L= m.C^2$...because it grows xxx     with speed of  xxxx.

2) My Love is like a  xxxx it goes on  xxxxx.

3) You must be the xxxxx  xxxx of xxxxx because I feel irrational around you.

4) The derivative of my love for you is xxxx because my love for you is xxxx.

5)  Honey, you are sweeter than xxxxxx.

6)  I am a mental math wizard. I can take square root of any number in seconds...don’t believe me..let us try with your xxxxx xxxxx.

7)  I heard you are good at algebra. Could you replace my ????  without asking ????.

Comment: what's the 'i' for in the tag?

Comment: It was accidental...will delete..thx

Comment: This is supposed to play little on math humor....supposed to be on the lighter side..

Comment: Would the [tag:humor] tag be appropriate?

Comment: I dint know we had one..I can edit ..we need to relax once in awhile from serious puzzle solving

Comment: Is the number of x supposed to indicate the amount of letters? The answers currently don't take this into account. If this isn't the case, you should consider this so that there aren't multiple solutions. Or is it to indicate that some words are used multiple times? Also, is it rot13(vagragvbany gung cneg frira hfrf na nygreangvir flzoby)?

Comment: Not really..it was kind of general guide .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

> My Love for you is like $L=m.C^2$...because it grows **massively** with speed of **light**.

2)

> My Love is like a **fractal** - it goes on **forever**.

3)

> You must be the **square root of 2** because I feel irrational around you.

4)

> The derivative of my love for you is **0** because my love for you is **constant**.

5)

> Honey, you are sweeter than **pi**.

6)

> I am a mental math wizard. I can take square root of any number in seconds...don’t believe me..let us try with your **phone number**.

7)

> I heard you are good at algebra. Could you replace my **ex** without asking **why**?

Comment: You are the closest to the answers I was looking for..so far

Answer (score 1):

1) My Love for you is like  $L= m.C^2$...because it grows xxx     with speed of  xxxx.

> Proportionally with speed of light

2) My Love is like a  xxxx it goes on  xxxxx.

> Circle it goes on forever

3) You must be the xxxxx  xxxx of xxxxx because I feel irrational around you.

> Square root of two

4) The derivative of my love for you is xxxx because my love for you is xxxx.

> Exponential because my love for you is exponential

5)  Honey, you are sweeter than xxxxxx.

> Pi

6)  I am a mental math wizard. I can take square root of any number in seconds...don’t believe me..let us try with your xxxxx xxxxx.

> Phone number

7)  I heard you are good at algebra. Could you replace my ????  without asking ????.

> Ex (x) without asking why (y)

Comment: You are pretty close